# Pytest: How to create a mock socket server to fake responses while testing an applications

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have an application for which I am writing tests using pytest to validate the behavior. The application is as follows

```
+-------------------+  
|   App under test  |  
+-------------------+    +------------------+  
|  external library |    | remote endpoint  |  
|   (socket client)-+--->| (socket server)  |  
+-------------------+    +------------------+
```

I am writing tests for the "App Under Test". The App imports external library and the socket client is an integral part of external library. I want to mock the remote endpoint and must be able to respond mock data when ever there was a request made and validate the "App Under Test"'s behavior. How to achieve this?

P.S. I am interested in the behavior of "app Under Test". The behavior of the app depends on the data it receives from the socket server. I am NOT interested in the underlying "external library".

Comment: If you are writing unit tests, mock the socket client instead of the server. If you are writing system tests, then either look at lightweight server implementations - for example, I like to use [`json-server`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) when in need of quickly mocking a REST API. Or write a stub server yourself. It's not about the sockets, rather about the network protocol the server should implement.

Comment: The socket client cannot be mock'd because it is not under my control. It is given by an external library. the App imports the external library and the socket client is provided as a part of that. the only thing under the control are "App under test" and "remote end point"